# Getting 404 Hits on URI -/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/- . How to deal

Tags: urls, amazon

how to deal with the above issue.
WordPress website hosted on AWS EC2 Bitnami

URI-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-

User-Agent Chrome 80.0.3987.163 | Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36    2021-06-06 06:54:33
URI -/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-

User-Agent Firefox 62.0 | Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0  2021-06-06 06:51:29

Comment: You could use a WordPress security plugin like Shield to track all 404s like this and then block the IP so it doesn't mess with you and use resources etc.